# Find documentation for "core" commands? Tried with texdef, seems tautological

Tags: macros, documentation

Thoughts behind the problem: I am trying to understand where I can find documentation for `\ifdefined` and `\ifx`. Even google does not seem to know where to find it.

Then I tried using texdef:

```
$texdef -t latex -F ifx
\ifx is defined by (La)TeX.

\ifx:
\ifx
```

That doesn't help me much.

Where can I find the documentation?

Comment: Some constructs are primitives, i.e. are not defined by other macros, they are given by the internals of the TeX binary, and can't be decomposed further.

Comment: I see, but are they explained anywhere?

Comment: `texdoc tex` ;-), or `The TeXBook` by D. E. Knuth or `TeX by Topic` by V. Eijkhout

Comment: Now that's nice. `\ifx` is in there, but not `\ifdefined`. Sorry for nitpicking :) Isn't that a TeX primitive then? I know the TeXBook, but those are not in there.

Comment: `\ifdefined` is an e-TeX extension (just checked!) --it's a new primitive . See `texdoc etex`, whereas `\@ifundefined` is purely LaTeX, see `texdoc source2e`. The given source above is about `Tex82`, which does not have such extensions. The 'problem' is the feature that it is possible to extend TeX and each extension introduces its own  features ;-)

Comment: Thank you! You were of great help. Armed with `texdoc tex`, `texdoc source2e`, and `texdoc etex`, I think I'll find what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some commands can't be decomposed further in (La)TeX -- they are TeX primitives, basically the `elementary particles` of TeX, from which other macros can be constructed to simplify the usage of (La)TeX.

In the end it is a compiler or interpreter that must be instructed to operate if has read `\ifx` or `\def` or `\openin`. The situation is similar to, say,  a `C` - source file: A `C` compiler must know what the basic commands `for` or `return` mean -- they are keywords and can't be reduced further.

That's why `texdef \ifx` will 'fail' in the sense that it can just report that `\ifx` is 'defined' as `\ifx`.

Looking up such constructs needs some experience and the knowledge that

- `texdoc tex` will report much of Knuth's TeX
- `texdoc etex` will give more insight of the 'new' e-TeX inventions introduced in the late 1990s
- `texdoc source2e` provides information about the LaTeX core.
- `texdoc texbytopic` will give a concise introduction how D.E. Knuth's version TeX works
- `texdoc pdftex` is nice to read about the PDF extensions.

In a similar manner, `luatex`, `xelatex` and `source3` are available for insights about `LuaTeX`, `XeTeX` and the `expl3` extensions.

For example, `\ifdefined` is a new primitive introduced by `e-TeX`, it has no further definition other than what is written in the binary.

Please note that `pdfTeX` introduces some more primitives such as `\pdfminorversion` etc.

Unfortunately, compiling the `The TeXBook` source is not possible still nowadays.

Comment: Since you mentioned pdfTeX, it might be worth explicitly adding `texdoc pdftex`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Fair point, I included the `pdftex` documentation reference as well

Comment: re `texbytopic`, should be specific that it's *knuth* tex, not any extended version.

Comment: _The TeXbook_ source _is_ freely available

Comment: @JosephWright: But not compilable, as far as I know?

Comment: `texbook.tex` is certainly available, not compilable, and rather hard to read without a printed copy to compare.  (a wonderful source when you see something and wonder how it was coded, but not a good place to look for explanations.)  `tex.web`, or better, "TeX: the program", is the canonical source for how, and usually why, something is done, but again, better in print.

Comment: +1; but what about, `texdoc luatex`?

Comment: @jon: Sure, that was missing, as well as `xelatex` and `source3`